# How to specify an email drop location

Tags: php, email, iis, drupal, outlook

I'm using Drupal CMS on top of PHP and IIS. When I send emails containing embed images, the images are not displayed in Outlook.

I'm trying to isolate the problem.

There is nothing in Drupal or Outlook which will allow me to view the complete message body with headers.

Is there a way to configure PHP to write the email to a folder on disk instead of sending the email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write it to a text file instead of sending, just need to find the place where it happens:

```
$folder=dirname(__FILE__)."/emaildir";
$txtfilename=time().'.txt';
$emailstr=$header . "/n" . $message . "/n";
```

instead of mailto() or whatever function just write to file

```
$fh=fopen($txtfilename,"w");
$fwrite($fh,$emailstr);
fclose($fh);
```

This is written from my head, you might want to check for mistakes but you get the picture